PutEmail processor can't handle special characters in filename
I have a process where I'm sending a csv file via email. I set filename in UpdateAttribute and put there a polish letter, then I use PutEmail and send this file as an attachment, however on the receiving email the file name is messed up, it starts with '=UTF-8' and ends with '=', and not only that 1 letter is wrong but also '_' characters are replaced by '=5F'. When I don't use polish letter there are no problems.
This is my PutEmail configuration, it is set to UTF-8 which shouldn't have any problems with polish letters.

I use Nifi 1.20, earlier I was using 1.10 and this process worked flawlessly.

Your problem description is very vague but this sounds like a bug in their client. This sounds like they are applying RFC2047 encoding on the Content-Disposition: header's filename keyword argument, but the correct protocol there is RFC2814

Try use a Content Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

@tonykoval tried already but didn't work, seems like it only affects message body

all those =XY is quote-printable variation used for email messages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word and it sounds ok for me. If previous version was working - I would compare delivered email headers from previous and current versions.
